# Can anyone explain IEnumerable and IEnumerator to me?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Can anyone explain `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` to me?

For example, when to use it over foreach? what's the difference between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`? Why do we need to use it?

Comment: This is the worst naming mixup since Java and JavaScript

Comment: @MatthewLock can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

> for example, when to use it over foreach?

You don't use `IEnumerable` "over" `foreach`.  Implementing `IEnumerable` makes using `foreach` *possible*.

When you write code like:

```
foreach (Foo bar in baz)
{
   ...
}
```

it's functionally equivalent to writing:

```
IEnumerator bat = baz.GetEnumerator();
while (bat.MoveNext())
{
   Foo bar = (Foo)bat.Current;
   ...
}
```

By "functionally equivalent," I mean that's actually what the compiler turns the code into. You can't use `foreach` on `baz` in this example *unless* `baz` implements `IEnumerable`.

`IEnumerable` means that `baz` implements the method

```
IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
```

The `IEnumerator` object that this method returns must implement the methods

```
bool MoveNext()
```

and

```
Object Current()
```

The first method advances to the next object in the `IEnumerable` object that created the enumerator, returning `false` if it's done, and the second returns the current object.

Anything in .NET that you can iterate over implements `IEnumerable`.  If you're building your own class, and it doesn't already inherit from a class that implements `IEnumerable`, you can make your class usable in `foreach` statements by implementing `IEnumerable` (and by creating an enumerator class that its new `GetEnumerator` method will return).

Comment: I think when the original poster said "over foreach", he meant "when should I call GetEnumerator() / MoveNext() explicitly instead of using a foreach loop."  For what it's worth.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right.  Well, the answer's implicit in my post:  it doesn't matter, since that's what the compiler does anyway.  So do what's easiest, i.e. use foreach.

Comment: This answer does not tell the whole story.  Enumerable objects need not implement IEnumerable; they only need to have a GetEnumerator method that returns an instance of a type that in turn has a `bool MoveNext()` method and a `Current` property of any type.  This "duck typing" approach was implemented in C# 1.0 as a way to avoid boxing when enumerating value-type collections.

Comment: Why can't an IEnumerable class call MoveNext(), Current, and Reset() directly instead of returning an IEnumerator that does it for it?

Comment: A class can implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerator.

Comment: Despertar, you probably meant class that implements IEnumerable :)

Comment: With the exlanation from above and working through [Workthrough: Implementing IEnumerable of (T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd145423.aspx) you have greate sources.

Comment: What I totally miss on this entire topic (considering all answers and comments) is that the state machine class which implements IEnumerator may also implement IDisposable and `foreach` will put a `using` block around the `while` loop in this case. Iterator methods using `try`-`finally` (or a `using`block) might result in a state machine class which implements IDisposable.

Comment: Is this sort of like a C++ `iterator`?

Comment: @Despertar the answer to your question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984091/why-is-ienumerablet-necessary-when-there-is-ienumeratort

Answer (score 203):

**The IEnumerable and IEnumerator Interfaces**

To begin examining the process of implementing existing .NET interfaces, let’s first look at the role of
IEnumerable and IEnumerator. Recall that C# supports a keyword named foreach that allows you to
iterate over the contents of any array type:

```
// Iterate over an array of items.
int[] myArrayOfInts = {10, 20, 30, 40};
foreach(int i in myArrayOfInts)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

While it might seem that only array types can make use of this construct, the truth of the matter is
any type supporting a method named GetEnumerator() can be evaluated by the foreach construct.To
illustrate, follow me!

Suppose we have a Garage class:

```
// Garage contains a set of Car objects.
public class Garage
{
   private Car[] carArray = new Car[4];
   // Fill with some Car objects upon startup.
   public Garage()
   {
      carArray[0] = new Car("Rusty", 30);
      carArray[1] = new Car("Clunker", 55);
      carArray[2] = new Car("Zippy", 30);
      carArray[3] = new Car("Fred", 30);
   }
}
```

Ideally, it would be convenient to iterate over the Garage object’s subitems using the foreach
construct, just like an array of data values:

```
// This seems reasonable ...
public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("***** Fun with IEnumerable / IEnumerator *****\n");
      Garage carLot = new Garage();
      // Hand over each car in the collection?
      foreach (Car c in carLot)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is going {1} MPH",
         c.PetName, c.CurrentSpeed);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Sadly, the compiler informs you that the Garage class does not implement a method named
GetEnumerator(). This method is formalized by the IEnumerable interface, which is found lurking within the System.Collections namespace.
Classes or structures that support this behavior advertise that they are able to expose contained
subitems to the caller (in this example, the foreach keyword itself). Here is the definition of this standard .NET interface:

```
// This interface informs the caller
// that the object's subitems can be enumerated.
public interface IEnumerable
{
   IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

As you can see, the GetEnumerator() method returns a reference to yet another interface named
System.Collections.IEnumerator. This interface provides the infrastructure to allow the caller to traverse the internal objects contained by the IEnumerable-compatible container:

```
// This interface allows the caller to
// obtain a container's subitems.
public interface IEnumerator
{
   bool MoveNext (); // Advance the internal position of the cursor.
   object Current { get;} // Get the current item (read-only property).
   void Reset (); // Reset the cursor before the first member.
}
```

If you want to update the Garage type to support these interfaces, you could take the long road and
implement each method manually. While you are certainly free to provide customized versions of
GetEnumerator(), MoveNext(), Current, and Reset(), there is a simpler way. As the System.Array type (as well as many other collection classes) already implements IEnumerable and IEnumerator, you can simply delegate the request to the System.Array as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
...
public class Garage : IEnumerable
{
   // System.Array already implements IEnumerator!
   private Car[] carArray = new Car[4];
   public Garage()
   {
      carArray[0] = new Car("FeeFee", 200);
      carArray[1] = new Car("Clunker", 90);
      carArray[2] = new Car("Zippy", 30);
      carArray[3] = new Car("Fred", 30);
   }
   public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
   {
      // Return the array object's IEnumerator.
      return carArray.GetEnumerator();
   }
}
```

After you have updated your Garage type, you can safely use the type within the C# foreach construct. Furthermore, given that the GetEnumerator() method has been defined publicly, the object user could also interact with the IEnumerator type:

```
// Manually work with IEnumerator.
IEnumerator i = carLot.GetEnumerator();
i.MoveNext();
Car myCar = (Car)i.Current;
Console.WriteLine("{0} is going {1} MPH", myCar.PetName, myCar.CurrentSpeed);
```

However, if you prefer to hide the functionality of IEnumerable from the object level, simply make
use of explicit interface implementation:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  // Return the array object's IEnumerator.
  return carArray.GetEnumerator();
}
```

By doing so, the casual object user will not find the Garage’s GetEnumerator() method, while the
foreach construct will obtain the interface in the background when necessary.

Adapted from the [Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework](http://www.apress.com/9781430242338)

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you! I do have one question though. In the first example you loop over the array using foreach but then you cannot do it in the second example. Is this because the array is in a class or because it contains objects?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. My only question is why not just have a method in `Garage` that gets `carArray`? That way you don't have to implement `GetEnumerator` yourself, since `Array` already does this. E.g. `foreach(Car c in carLot.getCars()) { ... }`

Comment: Answers like these deserves two ups instead of one...

Comment: While the code shows the point, it is worth while to mention that: 1-The Garage in the above code is just the constructor of the class. The constructor is not responsible for returning data to the caller. 2-We need to call a method that returns the cars array. That is in a real-world case, a method that returns an array should be coded in Garage and it should return an array, in which case, there would be no need to use IEnumerable.

Comment: Best Answer ever!

Answer (score 71):

Implementing IEnumerable means your class returns an IEnumerator object:

```
public class People : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        // return a PeopleEnumerator
    }
}
```

Implementing IEnumerator means your class returns the methods and properties for iteration:

```
public class PeopleEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    public void Reset()...

    public bool MoveNext()...

    public object Current...
}
```

That's the difference anyway.

Comment: Nice, this explains (together with the other posts) how to convert your class into one that you can use "foreach" on to iterate over its contents.

Answer (score 63):

### Explanation via Analogy + Code Walkthrough

Analogy: Imagine you are a detective on an aeroplane . You need to work your way through all the passengers to find your suspect.

An aeroplane can only do this, if it is:

1. countable, and
2. if it has a counter.

**What does countable mean?**

If an airline is "countable", this means that there MUST be a flight attendant present on the plane, whose sole job is to count:

1. The counter/flight attendant MUST start before the first passenger  2. (i.e. the flight attendant) MUST "move next" up the aisle to the first seat.
2. He/she is to then record: (i) who the person is in the seat, and (ii) their **current location** in the aisle.

The counter keeps going till he reaches the end of the plane.

**Let's tie this with the IEnumerables**

```
    foreach (Passenger passenger in Plane)
    // the airline hostess is now at the front of the plane
    // and slowly making her way towards the back
    // when she get to a particular passenger she gets some information
    // about the passenger and then immediately heads to the cabin
    // to let the captain decide what to do with it
    { // <---------- Note the curly bracket that is here.
        // we are now cockpit of the plane with the captain.
        // the captain wants to give the passenger free 
        // champaign if they support manchester city
        if (passenger.supports_mancestercity())
        {
            passenger.getFreeChampaign();
        } 
        else
        {
            // you get nothing! GOOD DAY SIR!
        }
    } //  <---- Note the curly bracket that is here!
      //  the hostess has delivered the information 
      //  to the captain and goes to the next person
      //  on the plane (if she has not reached the 
      //  end of the plane)
```

**Summary**

In other words, something is countable if it *has a counter*. And counter must (basically): (i) remember its place (*state*), (ii) be able to *move next*, (iii) and know about the *current* person he is dealing with.

Enumerable is just a fancy word for "countable".

Answer (score 25):

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable_members.aspx) implements GetEnumerator. When called, that method will return an [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator_members.aspx) which implements MoveNext, Reset and Current.

Thus when your class implements IEnumerable, you are saying that you can call a method (GetEnumerator) and get a new object returned (an IEnumerator) you can use in a loop such as foreach.

Answer (score 18):

Implementing IEnumerable enables you to get an IEnumerator for a list.

IEnumerator allows foreach style sequential access to the items in the list, using the yield keyword.

Before foreach implementation (in Java 1.4, for example), the way to iterate a list was to get an enumerator from the list, then ask it for the "next" item in the list, for as long as the value returned as the next item is not null.  Foreach simply does that implicitly as a  language feature, in the same way that lock() implements the Monitor class behind the scenes.

I expect foreach works on lists because they implement IEnumerable.

Comment: if its for a list why can't I just use foreach?

Comment: .Net duck types the foreach statement, but IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T> is the appropriate way to say that your class can be enumerated.

Answer (score 18):

- An object implementing **IEnumerable** allows others to visit each of its items *(by an enumerator)*.
- An object implementing **IEnumerator** is the doing the iteration. It's looping over an enumerable object.

Think of enumerable objects as of lists, stacks, trees.

Answer (score 15):

IEnumerable and IEnumerator (and their generic counterparts IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerator<T>) are base interfaces of [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) implementations in [.Net Framework Class Libray collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections).

*IEnumerable* is the most common interface you would see in the majority of the code out there. It enables the foreach loop, generators (think *yield*) and because of its tiny interface, it's used to create tight abstractions. [IEnumerable depends on IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator).

*IEnumerator*, on the other hand, provides a slightly lower level iteration interface. It's referred to as the [explicit iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.23_and_other_.NET_languages) which gives the programmer more control over the iteration cycle.

## IEnumerable

IEnumerable is a standard interface that enables iterating over collections that supports it (in fact, all collection types I can think of today implements *IEnumerable*). Compiler support allows language features like `foreach`. In general terms, it enables this [implicit iterator implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#Implicit_iterators).

#### foreach Loop

```
foreach (var value in list)
  Console.WriteLine(value);
```

I think `foreach` loop is one of the main reasons for using *IEnumerable* interfaces. `foreach` has a very succinct syntax and very easy to understand compared to classic *C* style for loops where you need to check the various variables to see what it was doing.

#### yield Keyword

Probably a lesser known feature is that *IEnumerable* also enables [generators in C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)#C.23) with the use of `yield return` and `yield break` statements.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> GetThings() {
   if (isNotReady) yield break;
   while (thereIsMore)
     yield return GetOneMoreThing();
}
```

#### Abstractions

Another common scenario in practice is using *IEnumerable* to provide minimalistic abstractions. Because it is a minuscule and read-only interface, you are encouraged to expose your collections as *IEnumerable* (rather than *List* for example). That way you are free to change your implementation without breaking your client's code (change List to a *LinkedList* for instance).

#### Gotcha

One behaviour to be aware of is that in streaming implementations (e.g. retrieving data row by row from a database, instead of loading all the results in memory first) you *cannot* iterate over the collection more than once. This is in contrast to in-memory collections like *List*, where you can iterate multiple times without problems. ReSharper, for example, [has a code inspection for *Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html).

## IEnumerator

IEnumerator, on the other hand, is the behind the scenes interface which makes *IEnumerble-foreach-magic* work. Strictly speaking, it enables explicit iterators.

```
var iter = list.GetEnumerator();
while (iter.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(iter.Current);
```

In my experience *IEnumerator* is rarely used in common scenarios due to its more verbose syntax and slightly confusing semantics (at least to me; e.g. *MoveNext()* returns a value as well, which the name doesn't suggest at all).

#### Use case for IEnumerator

I only used *IEnumerator* in particular (slightly lower level) libraries and frameworks where I was providing *IEnumerable* interfaces. One example is a data stream processing library which provided series of objects in a `foreach` loop even though behind the scenes data was collected using various file streams and serialisations.

**Client code**

```
foreach(var item in feed.GetItems())
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Library**

```
IEnumerable GetItems() {
    return new FeedIterator(_fileNames)
}

class FeedIterator: IEnumerable {
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return new FeedExplicitIterator(_stream);
    }
}

class FeedExplicitIterator: IEnumerator {
    DataItem _current;

    bool MoveNext() {
        _current = ReadMoreFromStream();
        return _current != null;           
    }

    DataItem Current() {
        return _current;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Differences between IEnumerable and IEnumerator :**

- IEnumerable uses IEnumerator internally.
- IEnumerable doesn't know which item/object is executing.
- Whenever we pass IEnumerator to another function, it knows the current position of item/object.
- Whenever we pass an IEnumerable collection to another function, it
  doesn't know the current position of item/object (doesn't know which item its executing)

  ***IEnumerable have one method GetEnumerator()***

> ```
> public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
> {
>     IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
> }
> ```

***IEnumerator has one property called Current and two methods, Reset() and MoveNext() (which is useful for knowing the current position of an item in a list).***

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
     object Current { get; }
     bool MoveNext();
     void Reset();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Implementing `IEnumerable` essentially means that the object can be iterated over. This doesn't necessarily mean it is an array as there are certain lists that can't be indexed but you can enumerate them.

`IEnumerator` is the actual object used to perform the iterations. It controls moving from one object to the next in the list.

Most of the time, `IEnumerable` & `IEnumerator` are used transparently as part of a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 7):

IEnumerable is a box that contains Ienumerator. IEnumerable is base interface for all the collections. foreach loop can operate if the collection implements IEnumerable. In the below code it explains the step of having our own Enumerator. Lets first define our Class of which we are going to make the collection.

```
public class Customer
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public long Mobile { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Now we will define the Class which will act as a collection for our class Customer. Notice that it is implementing the interface IEnumerable. So that we have to implement the method GetEnumerator. This will return our custom Enumerator.

```
public class CustomerList : IEnumerable
{
    Customer[] customers = new Customer[4];
    public CustomerList()
    {
        customers[0] = new Customer { Name = "Bijay Thapa", City = "LA", Mobile = 9841639665, Amount = 89.45 };
        customers[1] = new Customer { Name = "Jack", City = "NYC", Mobile = 9175869002, Amount = 426.00 };
        customers[2] = new Customer { Name = "Anil min", City = "Kathmandu", Mobile = 9173694005, Amount = 5896.20 };
        customers[3] = new Customer { Name = "Jim sin", City = "Delhi", Mobile = 64214556002, Amount = 596.20 };
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return customers.Count();
    }
    public Customer this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return customers[index];
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return customers.GetEnumerator(); // we can do this but we are going to make our own Enumerator
        return new CustomerEnumerator(this);
    }
}
```

Now we are going to create our own custom Enumerator as follow. So, we have to implement method MoveNext.

```
 public class CustomerEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        CustomerList coll;
        Customer CurrentCustomer;
        int currentIndex;
        public CustomerEnumerator(CustomerList customerList)
        {
            coll = customerList;
            currentIndex = -1;
        }

        public object Current => CurrentCustomer;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if ((currentIndex++) >= coll.Count() - 1)
                return false;
            else
                CurrentCustomer = coll[currentIndex];
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            // we dont have to implement this method.
        }
    }
```

Now we can use foreach loop over our collection like below;

```
    class EnumeratorExample
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            CustomerList custList = new CustomerList();
            foreach (Customer cust in custList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer Name:"+cust.Name + " City Name:" + cust.City + " Mobile Number:" + cust.Amount);
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

An understanding of the Iterator pattern will be helpful for you. I recommend reading the same.

[Iterator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/iterator-pattern.html)

At a high level the iterator pattern can be used to provide a standard way of iterating through collections of any type. 
We have 3 participants in the iterator pattern, the actual collection (client), the aggregator and the iterator. The aggregate is an interface/abstract class that has a method that returns an iterator. Iterator is an interface/abstract class that has methods allowing us to iterate through a collection.

*In order to implement the pattern we first need to implement an iterator to produce a concrete that can iterate over the concerned collection (client)
Then the collection (client) implements the aggregator to return an instance of the above iterator.*

Here is the UML diagram
[image: Iterator Pattern]

So basically in c#, IEnumerable is the abstract aggregate and IEnumerator is the abstract Iterator. IEnumerable has a single method GetEnumerator that is responsible for creating an instance of IEnumerator of the desired type. Collections like Lists implement the IEnumerable.

Example.
Lets suppose that we have a method `getPermutations(inputString)` that returns all the permutations of a string and that the method returns an instance of `IEnumerable<string>`

In order to count the number of permutations we could do something like the below.

```
 int count = 0;
        var permutations = perm.getPermutations(inputString);
        foreach (string permutation in permutations)
        {
            count++;
        }
```

The c# compiler more or less converts the above to

```
using (var permutationIterator = perm.getPermutations(input).GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (permutationIterator.MoveNext())
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

A Minor contribution.

As many of them explain about 'when to use' and 'use with foreach'.
I thought of adding Another **States Difference** here as requested in question about the difference between both IEnumerable an IEnumerator.

I created the below code sample based on the below discussion threads.

[IEnumerable , IEnumerator vs foreach, when to use what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085638/ienumerable-ienumerator-vs-foreach-when-to-use-what)
[What is the difference between IEnumerator and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619564/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerator-and-ienumerable)

Enumerator preserves the state (iteration position) between function calls while iterations the other hand Enumerable does not.

Here is the tested example with comments to understand.

**Experts please add/correct me.**

```
static void EnumerableVsEnumeratorStateTest()
{
    IList<int> numList = new List<int>();

    numList.Add(1);
    numList.Add(2);
    numList.Add(3);
    numList.Add(4);
    numList.Add(5);
    numList.Add(6);

    Console.WriteLine("Using Enumerator - Remembers the state");
    IterateFrom1to3(numList.GetEnumerator());

    Console.WriteLine("Using Enumerable - Does not Remembers the state");
    IterateFrom1to3Eb(numList);

    Console.WriteLine("Using Enumerable - 2nd functions start from the item 1 in the collection");
}

static void IterateFrom1to3(IEnumerator<int> numColl)
{
    while (numColl.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numColl.Current.ToString());

        if (numColl.Current > 3)
        {
            // This method called 3 times for 3 items (4,5,6) in the collection. 
            // It remembers the state and displays the continued values.
            IterateFrom3to6(numColl);
        }
    }
}

static void IterateFrom3to6(IEnumerator<int> numColl)
{
    while (numColl.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numColl.Current.ToString());
    }
}

static void IterateFrom1to3Eb(IEnumerable<int> numColl)
{
    foreach (int num in numColl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());

        if (num>= 5)
        {
            // The below method invokes for the last 2 items.
            //Since it doesnot persists the state it will displays entire collection 2 times.
            IterateFrom3to6Eb(numColl);
        }
    }
}

static void IterateFrom3to6Eb(IEnumerable<int> numColl)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (int num in numColl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed these differences:

A. We iterate the list in different way, foreach can be used for IEnumerable and while loop for IEnumerator.

B. IEnumerator can remember the current index when we pass from one method to another (it start working with current index) but IEnumerable  can't remember the index and it reset the index to beginning. More in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jd3yUjGc9M0

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` both are interfaces in C#.

`IEnumerable` is an interface defining a single method `GetEnumerator()` that returns an `IEnumerator` interface.

This works for read-only access to a collection that implements that `IEnumerable` can be used with a `foreach` statement.

`IEnumerator` has two methods, `MoveNext` and `Reset`. It also has a property called `Current`.

The following shows the implementation of IEnumerable and IEnumerator.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Enudemo
{

    class Person
    {
        string name = "";
        int roll;

        public Person(string name, int roll)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.roll = roll;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name : " + name + "\t Roll : " + roll);
        }

    }


    class Demo : IEnumerable
    {
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();

        public Demo()
        {
            list1.Add(new Person("Shahriar", 332));
            list1.Add(new Person("Sujon", 333));
            list1.Add(new Person("Sumona", 334));
            list1.Add(new Person("Shakil", 335));
            list1.Add(new Person("Shruti", 336));
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
           return list1.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Demo d = new Demo();  // Notice here. it is simple object but for 
                                //IEnumerator you can get the collection data

            foreach (Person X in d)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(X);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
/*
Output : 

Name : Shahriar  Roll : 332
Name : Sujon     Roll : 333
Name : Sumona    Roll : 334
Name : Shakil    Roll : 335
Name : Shruti    Roll : 336
  */
```