# What is the difference between IEnumerator and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ienumerator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone explain IEnumerable and IEnumerator to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me)

What are the differences between IEnumerator and IEnumerable?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me

Comment: This article might help you.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/ienumerable-vs-ienumerator-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 135, accepted):

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is an interface that defines one method **GetEnumerator** which returns an **[IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)** interface, this in turn allows readonly access to a collection. A collection that implements IEnumerable can be used with a foreach statement.

Definition

```
IEnumerable 

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();

IEnumerator

public object Current;
public void Reset();
public bool MoveNext();
```

Comment: This article might help you.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/219d4d/ienumerable-vs-ienumerator-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: I would like to add that it is not an absolute requirement to implement `IEnumerable` to use the class with a `foreach` statement. Only a matching `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method is required.

Comment: The actual requirement for the foreach loop is even less restrictive and not bound to those interfaces at all. The compiler performs pattern matching. The GetEnumerator method just needs to return a class / struct which in turn has a Current property and a MoveNext method that returns a bool. I can highly recommend [Eric Lipperts blog post about pattern matching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern/)

Answer (score 79):

An `IEnumerator` is a thing that can enumerate: it has the `Current` property and the `MoveNext` and `Reset` methods (which in .NET code you probably won't call explicitly, though you could).

An `IEnumerable` is a thing that can be enumerated...which simply means that it has a GetEnumerator method that returns an `IEnumerator`.

Which do you use?  The only reason to use `IEnumerator` is if you have something that has a nonstandard way of enumerating (that is, of returning its various elements one-by-one), and you need to define how that works.  You'd create a new class implementing `IEnumerator`.  But you'd still need to return that `IEnumerator` in an `IEnumerable` class.

For a look at what an enumerator (implementing `IEnumerator<T>`) looks like, see any `Enumerator<T>` class, such as the ones contained in `List<T>`, `Queue<T>,` or `Stack<T>`.  For a look at a class implementing `IEnumerable`, see any standard collection class.

Comment: Then why do we need this IEnumerable abstraction, if the only thing it does is just provide an access to Enumerator? Why don't just use Enumerator instead

Comment: @xalz, they do two different things.  `IEnumerable` answers the question: _Can_ I enumerate my elements?  `IEnumerator` answers the question: _How_ do I enumerate my elements?  If you have ten different collections that all enumerate the same way, you wouldn't want to have to define how each one enumerates separately.  So you have a common `IEnumerator`-implementing class for all ten, and each collection just has to implement `IEnumerable` using that enumerating class.  It's about separation of concerns, treating _holding_ data and _enumerating_ data as separate operations.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answered my question rather than listing differences between 2 classes. IEnumerator is a class that enumerates collections. A class that implements IEnumerable returns an IEnumerator. A class that implements IEnumerator has custom enumeration logic.

Answer (score 20):

An `Enumerator` shows you the items in a list or collection.
Each instance of an Enumerator is at a certain position (the 1st element, the 7th element, etc) and can give you that element (`IEnumerator.Current`) or move to the next one (`IEnumerator.MoveNext`).  When you write a `foreach` loop in C#, the compiler generates code that uses an Enumerator.

An `Enumerable` is a class that can give you `Enumerator`s.  It has a method called `GetEnumerator` which gives you an `Enumerator` that looks at its items.  When you write a `foreach` loop in C#, the code that it generates calls `GetEnumerator` to create the `Enumerator` used by the loop.

Comment: That blog post is rather inaccurate.

Answer (score 12):

`IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` are both interfaces. `IEnumerable` has just one method called `GetEnumerator`. This method returns (as all methods return something including void) another type which is an interface and that interface is `IEnumerator`. When you implement enumerator logic in any of your collection class, you implement `IEnumerable` (either generic or non generic). `IEnumerable` has just one method whereas `IEnumerator` has 2 methods (`MoveNext` and `Reset`) and a property `Current`. For easy understanding consider `IEnumerable` as a box that contains `IEnumerator` inside it (though not through inheritance or containment). See the code for better understanding:

```
class Test : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object Current
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```