# life without IEumerable but with IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone explain IEnumerable and IEnumerator to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me)
>   [What is the difference between IEnumerator and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619564/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerator-and-ienumerable)

We can implement IEnumerator or its generic version and thus use it directly.

So why do we require IEnumerable? Do we require IEnumerable to give a new set of data or is it something else!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/558304/759701 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/619564/759701

Comment: Mainly I'd like to ask you what are you looking for to know with your question :D

Comment: why do we require ienumerable when the same thing can be achieved through ienumerator?

Comment: @Anirudha we require IEnumerable because it provides a convenient source for the IEnumerator object.

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerable` specifies an aspect of a class: it tells you that can be enumerated. `IEnumerator` is implemented by classes that perform the actual job of providing results during the enumeration. These are two different things.

Putting it another way:

- We need `IEnumerable` as a way to say "this class contains enumerable data"
- We need `IEnumerator` so that *after we determine that an object can be enumerated*, we can tell it "start giving me the data in that object one by one"

Comment: thanks..but is it that ienuerable is used becuz it gives a new set of data so that multiple classes can acces that data individually

Comment: @Anirudha: `IEnumerable` just tells you that you can get an `IEnumerator` out of an object. The `IEnumerator` is what allows you to actually enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IEnumerator without IEnumerable. Implementing an IEnumerable requires implementing an IEnumerator, but not the opposite.

With IEnumerable you can get the nice syntax candy of [foreach](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022).

Comment: thts right but y do we require ienumerable when the same thing can be done wid ienumerator

Comment: @Anirudha Where to get the enumerator for a given collection?  Call its `GetEnumerator()` method.  How do we know the collection has such a method?  Because the collection implements IEnumerable.