# Why is IEnumerable<T> necessary when there is IEnumerator<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

**Disclaimer:** I understand the difference between `IEnumerable<T>` and  `IEnumerator<T>` and how to use both. This is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619564/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerator-and-ienumerable).

This is more of a design question - since `IEnumerator<T>` already encapsulates all the necessary information (`.Current`, `.MoveNext()`) about something that can be enumerated, then what's the point of introducing a type (`IEnumerable<T>`) whose sole purpose is to return an instance of the former?

To be specific:

1. Why can't `foreach` be designed to iterate directly through an `IEnumerator<T>`, like so:

   ```
   // foreach (var e in anEnumerator) { //... }
   while (anEnumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       doSomething(anEnumerator.Current);
   }
   ```
2. Why can't Linq be built based directly off of `IEnumerator<T>`?

Comment: It certainly *could* have been, but without talking to the .NET design team, I doubt you will get much of an answer here.

Comment: There will presumably be other situations (beyond `foreach` loops) where an interface that promises "capable of providing an enumerator" is necessary.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's been designed like so doesn't mean there isn't a reason behind. For everybody's benefit of learning something that potentially have a reason, I DON'T agree this should be closed.

Comment: It doesn't make sense: A `List<T>` is *enumerable*, it's not an *enumerator*. A list shouldn't have to keep track of its "current" element in the context of however many clients are enumerating it.

Comment: I'd say IEnumerable acts like Func<IEnumerator> meaning not a live enumerator but the way to obtain it. But Func<IEnumerator> is not an interface, correct?

Comment: @KFL I'm sure there *is* a reason behind it, its just the SO community (with the notable exception of Eric Lippert) doesn't know the answer. It is inherently *opinion-based*.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET While we may not be able to provide the exact thinking behind this decision at the time, the effects of the decision and benefits provided are very easy to explain.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I agree (and upvoted your excellent answer). Perhaps the question just need to be phrased differently. Either way, it has a great (objective) answer, and it should benefit the community as a whole. Everybody wins, and I'm happy with that :)

Comment: How would you implement `from x in someList from y in someList select new {x, y}` to enumerate the *Cartesian product of a list with itself* in your proposed scheme?

Comment: Other than the other two questions aren't tagged as answered, how *is* this question not a duplicate?  The answer simply explains the differences.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The two interfaces each represent very different concepts.  `IEnumerable<T>` is something that "allows enumeration", where `IEnumerator<T>` is the representation of the enumeration itself.

If you were to merge these together, it would be impossible to enumerate a single collection more than once at the same time (without some other mechanism in place).  For example, two threads doing a `foreach` over an array would no longer work, where that is perfectly acceptable in the current design.

Comment: +1. You don't even have to involve threading: nested enumerations over the same collection also wouldn't work.

Comment: Conceptually, the two concepts are both conceptions.

Comment: Short answer is that `IEnumerable` represents a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for `IEnumeration` instances.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the current design allows different kinds of enumerators for the same enumerable, i.e. reverse enumators.

Comment: @LorentzVedeler How do you get that different kinds? IEnumerable have only one method without params.

Comment: @tower120 if you have an implementation of IEnumerable<T>, you could have a field with the IEnumerator<T> and a method Reverse() which changes the field to a new ReverseEnumerator and then when the GetEnumerator-method is called, you would return tha instead of the regular IEnumerator-implementation.

Comment: @LorentzVedeler - Yes, indeed. But this would be very unclear. You would "never" know in which way you go next call :))