# how do I create GetEnumerator of my circular list?

Tags: c#, foreach, enumerator, circular-list

I have to create my own circular list, I using the generic one.

first i create the `Node<D>` class which represents the data and the next of the element

```
      private class Node<D> {
            public D info;
            public Node<D> next;

            public Node() {

            }

            public Node(D p) {
                info = p;
            }
        }
```

To create the circular list, I create the `circularList<T>` class. this class using `Node<>` as item of the element.

Here is the `CircularList<T>` class

```
class CircularList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    public Node<T> start;
    public Node<T> rear;
    public int count = 0;
    public CircularList(T firstItem) {
        start = new Node<T>(firstItem);
        rear = start;
        rear.next = start;
    }

    public void Insert(T newItem) {
        //Inserting code here
    }

    public void Update(T oldItem, T newItem) {
        //Updating code is here
    }

    public void Delete(T theItem) {
        //deleting code is here
    }


}
```

when I start to loop using `foreach`

```
foreach(string item in CircularList<string>){

}
```

I got an error says that the `circularlist` class needs `GetEnumerator()`.

Actually I can loop all of my circular list, but I am using `do-while` and I need `Node<T>` to start the loop. but I don't want using `Node` and `do-while`.

How do I create the GetEnumerator()?

Any help appreciated. :)

Thank you

**Note**: I really-really don't understand about `IEnumerable` and those things, please go easy with the example and explanation.

Comment: Did you implement `GetEnumerator()` from `IEnumerable` interface? foreach requires `GetEnumerator()`. You should be getting the `compile` time error if you have not already implemented.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't know what to return.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to implement `GetEnumerator()` method from `IEnumerable` for the `foreach` to work.

Use something like following:

```
public class CircularList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> mylist = new List<T>();

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mylist[index];
        }
        set
        {
            this.mylist.Insert(index, value);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.mylist.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

`mylist` maintains the list of type `T` which you would `insert`, `update` and `delete`.

**EDIT**

`myList` is just the backing storage of your "custom" list. As long as you are implementing your underlying functionality correctly, `myList` could be array, arraylist and so on. 
For simplicity, I've used `List<T>` here which already implements the interface `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`( notice `IEnumera**tor**` not `IEnumerable`).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619564/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerator-and-ienumerable) answer for more details on the difference between `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`

Moreover, The `foreach` statement hides the complexity of the enumerators.
See [IEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

The compiler turns the `foreach` into something like this:

```
CircularList<string> testList=new CircularList<string>();

IEnumerator testEnumerator= testList.GetEnumerator();
while (testEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
  string yourForEachIteratorVariable = (string)testEnumerator.Current
   ...
}
```

> Please note that the codes here are only for the illustration purposes. You could/should modify to make it more flexible and "performant" according to your need/requirement.

And for **linked list**, you don't need a backing `List<T>`, you could simply add/insert on your `head` node and implement GetEnumerator() something like below:

```
 public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
   var node = start;
   while(node != null)
   {
    yield return node.info;
    node = node.next;
 }
}
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
 return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.... i didn't see the last one **mylist maintains the list of type T which you would insert, update and delete.**. +1 + accepted

Comment: Using a backing list does defeat the purpose of presenting a linked list to the consumer.

Comment: @Enigmativity, please see my edited answer, the backing list type is only for the purpose of illustration for "simplicity".

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown - It's a bit misleading to suggest that this is the correct approach for the OP. It's generally the right approach, but not for a linked-list.