# Should a class implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I know a class can implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerator (its GetEnumerator method will simply "return this" and there won't be any compile-time issue, but I've read that we should avoid this practice as this can cause problems if we called `GetEnumerator()` a second time before the first enumeration was completed.

I'm still confused about why we should avoid this and how can it cause a problem. It would be great if someone could explain this in detail for greater understanding.

Comment: but you answered on this - `this can cause problems if we called GetEnumerator() a second time before the first enumeration was completed`

Comment: An Enumerator has to keep a State (where was I). And that doesn't mix with "call GetEnumerator() a second time before the first enumeration was completed"

Comment: You can read this: [What is the difference between IEnumerator and IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619564/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerator-and-ienumerable) for reference.