# C# Differences between the various System.Collection(.Generic) types

Tags: c#, collections

i am quite confused about the differences between the various types in the C# language. specifically

- IEnumerable
- IEnumerator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain IEnumerable and IEnumerator to me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` represents a sequence which *can be enumerated* - such as a list.

`IEnuerator<T>` effectively represents a cursor *within a sequence*.

So imagine you have a sequence - you can iterate over that with several "cursors" at the same time. For example:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "First", "Second", "Third" };
foreach (string x in names)
{
    foreach(string y in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}");
    }
}
```

Here, `List<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, and the `foreach` loops each call `GetEnumerator()` to retrieve an `IEnumerator<string>`. So when we're in the middle of the inner loop, there are two *independent* cursors iterating over a single sequence.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` a collection that can be enumerated.

`IEnumerator` the thing that actually manages location through the collection, provides access to the current item and allows you to move on to the next.

So one would use an `IEnumerator` to walk through an `IEnumerable`.