# What's Enumerator in an object?

Tags: .net, enumerator

This line of code confuses me:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>();
IDictionaryEnumerator ca = cache.GetEnumerator();
while (ca.MoveNext())
{
  keys.Add(ca.Key.ToString());
}
```

What is an Enumerator? Is it connected to Enumerations? I try to find a tutorial on enumerators, but without success. Hope someone will have patience to explain it to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain IEnumerable and IEnumerator to me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show what type 'cache' actually is but your code is equivalent to :

```
foreach(var ca in cache)  
{
   keys.Add(ca.Key.ToString();
}
```

`foreach()` uses the Enumerator as well, but cleaner through compiler-generated code.

Comment: I see. Which one is faster? Do you know that?

Comment: @askmo: If you have to ask, use neither. But these 2 are the same.