# Nested Coroutines Using IEnumerator vs IEnumerable in Unity3d

Tags: c#, iterator, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm using the StartCoroutine method of [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/5) and I have a question concerning nested coroutines.

Typically, nested coroutines might look something like this:

```
void Start() { StartCoroutine(OuterCoroutine()); }

IEnumerator OuterCoroutine()
{
    //Do Some Stuff . . .
    yield return StartCoroutine(InnerCoroutine());
    //Finish Doing Stuff . . .
}

IEnumerator InnerCoroutine()
{
    //Do some other stuff . . .
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    //Finish Doing that other stuff . . .
}
```

That's all well and fine, but it's really not necessary. The same effect can be achieved like this:

```
void Start() { StartCoroutine(OuterCoroutine()); }

IEnumerator OuterCoroutine()
{
    //Do Some Stuff . . .
    IEnumerator innerCoroutineEnumerator = InnerCoroutine().GetEnumerator();
    while(innerCoroutineEnumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return innerCoroutineEnumerator.Current;
    //Finish Doing Stuff . . .
}

IEnumerable InnerCoroutine()
{
    //Do some other stuff . . .
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    //Finish Doing that other stuff . . .
}
```

I have found this method produces less garbage (which can be an issue in Unity) than having multiple StartCoroutines; therefore it is very useful, especially when dealing with many nested layers.

**Now my question is:**

Instead of using `IEnumerable InnerCoroutine(){}` and getting the enumerator like so:

```
IEnumerator innerCoroutineEnumerator = InnerCoroutine().GetEnumerator();
```

I'd like to use `IEnumerator InnerCoroutine(){}` and get the enumerator like this:

```
IEnumerator innerCoroutineEnumerator = InnerCoroutine();
```

Are they the same?

In addition to being faster in my testing, this method will allow me to use the "inner coroutine" method via the normal StartCoroutine method, which might useful down the road.

I have done testing, and as far as I can tell, both techniques are effectively doing the same thing, but I am still relatively new at this whole coding thing, so there is the chance that I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, both way of writing produce the same result.

This is more a C# question, Unity3D is just using those type in their coroutine system. You might find [this post answering in more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/558428/62921) your question.

However, I am not sure what you mean by

> I have found this method produces less garbage (which can be an issue in Unity)

since both method should produce the same result.At this point it's more of a choice of code style.

I personally prefer the `StartCoroutine(InnerCoroutine())` one liner, where `InnerCoroutine()` would return an `IEnumerator`. I don't see the point in returning an IEnumerable for `InnerCoroutine()` and then getting its enumerator afterwards.

Comment: It's convenient to return IEnumerable if you plan to manually foreach over the contents of the enumerator block, but again, it's just syntactic sugar since you could achieve the same result with an IEnumerator using a while (iterator.MoveNext()) {} loop. The one difference is that Dispose is guaranteed to be called automatically for you on the IEnumerable when foreach is used, whereas the IEnumerator doesn't have that same benefit. It's not clear when or how this becomes useful though.